# SQLAlchemy: get rows matching elements from two lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

i'm new to SQL and SQLAlchemy. I have already searched on SO and elsewhere and tried to understand the SQLAlchemy documentation, but didn't find a satisfying solution to my problem.

---

I have a table `colours` with columns `colour` and `farbe` and the following rows:

```
red     rot
green   gruen
yellow  gelb
blue    blau
black   schwarz
white   weiss
purple  violett
grey    grau
cyan    tuerkis
```

and in python i have two lists:

```py
la = ['b', 'w']
lb = ['l', 'e']
```

Both lists can have a dozent or more elements.

With SQLAlchemy, how can i get all rows which have one of `la` **and** one of `lb` in it contents (the number of elements in either `la` and `lb` is unknown)? Hereby should all columns be searched.

For my above example the resulting SQL query is something like:

```sql
SELECT * FROM colours WHERE
(
  (colour LIKE "%b%" OR colour LIKE "%w%") AND
  (colour LIKE "%l%" OR colour LIKE "%e%")
)
OR
(
  (farbe LIKE "%b%" OR farbe LIKE "%w%") AND
  (farbe LIKE "%l%" OR farbe LIKE "%e%");
)
```

result should be:

```
yellow  gelb
blue    blau
black   schwarz
white   weiss
```

My current solution is (**Update**: 5.5.2016):

```py
query = session.query(Colours)
session.query(Colours.colour, Colours.farbe)
def GetFilter(color):
    fltr = or_()
    for c in color:
        t = u'%{0}%'.format(c)
        fltr = or_(fltr,
                    Colours.farbe.like(t),
                    Colours.colour.like(t)
                    )
    return fltr
if la and lb:
    fltra = GetFilter(la)
    fltrb = GetFilter(lb)
    query = session.query(Colours).filter(fltra).filter(fltrb)
elif la:
    fltra = GetFilter(la)
    query = session.query(Colours).filter(fltra)
elif lb:
    fltrb = GetFilter(lb)
    query = session.query(Colours).filter(fltrb)
else:
    query = session.query(Colours)

for i in query.all():
    print i.id, i.colour, i.farbe
```

How can this be done better? In my full script i have six columns that should be searched. How can it be done better without those nearly the same lines (`Colours.xxxx.like('%'+a+'%')`)?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I see what you are trying todo. You will need to join the table to itself. So you will join on the ID of the row (whatever they have in common)

```
select * from colours c1, colours c2 where c1.colour = "*la*" 
join c2 where c2.ID=c1.ID and c2.colour= "*lb*"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i need to have it in SQLAlchemy and it must be expandable (la, lb, lc...l#).